# Enumerables sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the following sets enumerable?

a) The set of all the finite sequences of rational numbers

b) The set of all the infinite sequences of natural numbers

c) The set of real numbers

d) The set of the formulas from calculus of predicate on the lexical $L=[R^2,P^1,f^2,g^3]$ which are deductibles from the premise $∀x(R(g(x,f(x,x),x),x)\supset P(x))$

I'm not sure about this, somebody tell me that a is enumerable, and b is not. But why? The c I guess that I could use Cantor proof, but how I said I'm not sure about this, and the last one I really don´t know. I hope you can help me with something. Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer to (c) is quite well-known.

Answer (score 0):

a is enumerable because we can construct it with diagonalization. We make a list of all the possible length 1 rational number sequences, then length 2, etc. Then we read this infinite list of infinite lists by the diagonals.

b is not enumerable because if you take a subset of b, namely the sequences where the natural numbers are limited to $0 \leq n \leq 9$, and you put a $0.$ in front of it, each set is exactly a real number between $0$ and $1$, meaning that $b$ contains $c$.

c is so well studied and explained there's no point repeating it here. Look for Cantor's proof.

d I have no idea, hopefully someone else knows.

Answer (score 0):

a and d are enumerable since they are finite sequences from an enumerable set. Basically you construct an enumeration by the same way you enumerate $\mathbb Q$ except you will have to enumerate over sequences of different length, but you simply interleave them.

b and c are not enumerable since they are basically infinite sequences from a set with at least two elements ($a$ and $b$). You can use Cantors proof here. You just assume you have an enumeration $x_j$ and then construct an element $u$ not in that enumeration by taking $u(k) = a$ if $x_k(k)\ne a$ and $u(k)=b$ if $x_k(k) = a$.